# Find an $\omega \in \text{Alt}^2(\Bbb R^4)$ such that $\omega \wedge \omega \ne 0$.

Tags: differential-geometry, exterior-algebra

> Find an $\omega \in \text{Alt}^2(\Bbb R^4)$ such that $\omega \wedge \omega \ne 0$.

What is the intuition for the problem? Since $\omega \in \text{Alt}^2(\Bbb R^4)$ we know that $\omega : \Bbb R^4 \to \Bbb R$ is an alternating $4$-linear map. That is $$\omega(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) \in \Bbb R$$ and that $$\omega(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) = -\omega(x_2,x_1,x_3,x_4)$$ for example.

I've also seen that this $\omega \wedge \omega$ can be tought of as the volume of a parallelotope so is the question asking me to find an $\omega \in \text{Alt}^2(\Bbb R^4)$ such that the "volume" with itself is nonzero?

Was it not true that the wedge product of any $n$-form with itself was always $0$?

Comment: Hint: you know that $dx^1\wedge\cdots \wedge dx^4 \neq 0$, right? Can you find a linear combination of $dx^i\wedge dx^j$, for some $i$ and $j$, such that it solves the problem, for example, such that its wedge product with itself is $dx^1\wedge \cdots \wedge dx^4$?

Comment: @Didier Unfortunately I don't know this result yet. Differential forms have not yet been introduced at this point as I'm still working on alternating and exterior algebra.

Comment: Then replace $dx^i$ with $e_i^*$, where $e_1,\ldots,e_4$ is the canonical basis and $e_i^*$ are elements of the dual basis.

Comment: How do you (attempt to) prove that the wedge product of any $n$-form with itself is $0$?

Comment: Another hint: look at what happens in dimension $2$, by considering $\omega = e_1^* + e_2^*$ in $\Bbb R^2$. You should find that $\omega\wedge \omega$ is twice the determinant $e_1^*\wedge e_2^*$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Okay I see I was wrong. The wedge product with any _vector_ with itself is zero. Not an $n$-form.

Comment: @Didier So considering the given bases that you proposed, your first hint suggests some linear combination of $e^*_i \wedge e^*_j$ such that it solves the problem somehow?

Comment: By the way, if $\omega\in \text{Alt}^2$, how are you evaluating on $4$ vectors? … Do you know something about $\omega\wedge\eta$ versus $\eta\wedge\omega$ for alternating $k$ and $\ell$ tensors?

Comment: @TedShifrin I don't know enough so that I could reply to you on why we couldn't do this. This is problem $2.2$ from the book "from calculus to cohomology".

Comment: @SleepWalker Exactly. In dimension $2$, the linear combination $\omega =e_1^* + e_2^*$ is a solution. In dimension $4$, a particular linear combination $\omega = \sum \lambda_{ij}e_i^*\wedge e_j^*$ will be solution. More generally in dimension $2n$, a clever combination if $e_{i_1}^*\wedge\cdots \wedge e_{i_n}^*$ will work.

Comment: @Didier $$\omega=e_1^*+e_2^*$$ $$\omega\wedge\omega=e_1^*\wedge e_1^*+e_1^*\wedge e_2^*+e_2^*\wedge e_1^*+e_2^*\wedge e_2^*$$ $$=0+e_1^*\wedge e_2^*+(-e_1^*\wedge e_2^*)+0$$ $$=0$$

Comment: @mr_e_man You're right, my comment above has a flaw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily see from the definition of the exterior (wedge) product that it is antisymmetric **on 1-forms**, i.e. $\omega\wedge\eta = -\eta\wedge\omega \;\,\forall\omega,\eta\in\mathrm{Alt}(\mathbb{R}^4)$, which implies that this product is alternating **on 1-forms**, i.e. $\omega\wedge\omega = 0 \;\,\forall\omega\in\mathrm{Alt}(\mathbb{R}^4)$.

This result is not valid in general; indeed, taking a $k$-form $\omega\in\mathrm{Alt}^k(\mathbb{R}^4)$ and a $l$-form $\eta\in\mathrm{Alt}^l(\mathbb{R}^4)$, you can prove that $\omega\wedge\eta = (-1)^{kl}\,\eta\wedge\omega$. In consequence, for higher-degree forms, the exterior product is alternating for odd degrees only, i.e. $\omega\wedge\omega = 0 \;\,\forall\omega\in\mathrm{Alt}^{2k+1}(\mathbb{R}^4)$. Note that the product with itself can vanish for an even-degree form, but it is not true in general.

As Didier suggests in the comments, we could find a form $\omega\in\mathrm{Alt}^k(\mathbb{R}^4)$ whose "square" $\omega\wedge\omega$ gives the volume form (determinant) $e_1^* \wedge e_2^* \wedge e_3^* \wedge e_4^* \in\mathrm{Alt}^4(\mathbb{R}^4)$, where the vectors $e_i^*$ constitute the canonical dual basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$. As $\omega\wedge\omega\in\mathrm{Alt}^{2k}(\mathbb{R}^4)$, we must take $k=2$. Moreover, since the exterior product is alternating on 1-forms, as previously said, no dual basis vector should appear twice, that is why we could take $\omega = e_1^* \wedge e_2^* + e_3^* \wedge e_4^*$ for instance. Let's now compute
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\omega\wedge\omega 
   &=& (e_1^* \wedge e_2^* + e_3^* \wedge e_4^*) \wedge (e_1^* \wedge e_2^* + e_3^* \wedge e_4^*) \\
   &=& e_1^* \wedge e_2^* \wedge e_3^* \wedge e_4^* + e_3^* \wedge e_4^* \wedge e_1^* \wedge e_2^* \\
   &=& 2\, e_1^* \wedge e_2^* \wedge e_3^* \wedge e_4^* \neq 0
\end{array}
$$
since $(e_3^* \wedge e_4^*) \wedge (e_1^* \wedge e_2^*) = (-1)^{2\cdot2}\, (e_1^* \wedge e_2^*) \wedge (e_3^* \wedge e_4^*) = e_1^* \wedge e_2^* \wedge e_3^* \wedge e_4^*$.

Answer (score 2):

Some extra info about this problem

1. A two form $\omega \in \wedge^2(V)$ is decomposable if and only if $\omega \wedge \omega = 0$ (  per the Plucker conditions)
2. If $\dim V = 2k$ and $\omega = \sum m_{ij}\cdot  v_i \wedge v_j \in \wedge^2(V)$, then $\omega\wedge \omega \wedge \cdots \wedge \omega= k! \cdot Pf(M) \cdot v_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge v_{2k}$, where $Pf(M)$ is the [Pffafian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pfaffian#Alternative_definitions) of the skew-matrix $M= (m_{ij})$.